# awk command in unix - inserting records in to oracle

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to generate insert statements in unix shell script and execute it using sqlplus command. I wrote the below code  .

```
    awk 'BEGIN { for (i = 1; i < 3;  i++) 
printf "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(%s,%d,%d);\n","\047TEST-FROM-UNIX\047",$i,$i}'| sqlplus -s username/passwrd
```

Is there any other good practice to do the insertion from unix ?

It generates the output

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('TEST-FROM-UNIX',0,0); 

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('TEST-FROM-UNIX',0,0);
```

But the required output is

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('TEST-FROM-UNIX',1,1); 

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('TEST-FROM-UNIX',2,2);
```

Could some one please tell, What change in the above code will achieve this ?  Thanks for your time..

Comment: for (i = 1; i < $1;  i++)  : I changed the for loop to have $1 as max value (command line argument). Now the code does not generate any output.

Comment: you are going to use a script to do all this operation naa

Comment: yes, I just wanted to control the number of records this scripts generates, from the command line... Thats the reason I changed the for loop to have $1. but it doesn't work.

Comment: You also could have just as easily done this in a simple bash loop to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `$` with `i` :

```
 awk 'BEGIN { for (i = 1; i < 3;  i++) 
 printf "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(%s,%d,%d);\n","\047TEST-FROM-UNIX\047",i,i}'
```

If you want to do it with variable max value then you have to create a script file with this code :

```
awk -v rows=$1 'BEGIN { for (i = 1; i < rows;  i++) 
printf "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(%s,%d,%d);\n","\047TEST-FROM-UNIX\047",i,i}'
```